# Online - Create list/DL from custom template using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I've created a custom list template and now I'm trying to create a new list with this template using a SharePoint workflow.

I thought using SharePoint REST API could be the solution, but I can't find the way to create a new list using this template.

Is there a SharePoint web services to use to create a new list with a previously created template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** you can't create a list **based on** a template via `REST API` or `SharePoint Workflow`.

**But,** you can create a list **based on** `BaseTemplateID` via SharePoint Designer by using this endpoint

```
http://siteURL/_api/web/lists
```

Where `BaseTemplate` of Custom List is **100**, the Document library is **101**.

Check the details steps at [How To Create A List Using HTTP Web Service In SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you think a solutions could be to create the list and then create fields following this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/142562/20605 ?

Comment: I would suggest this solution, but I thought you need to create a list from the template that has content! I think it is a suitable solution

Comment: No, I don't need the content, just the structure (custom columns) . So I still can't create a list from a template via REST, but I have to create the list with basics columns and then create each single column, is that correct?

Comment: One thing that I think you should care about it that is When you will run this workflow? on item added or changed? your theory is correct but you should care about the workflow event that will depend on your business requirements!

Comment: I'm running this workflow only when new item is created. ;)

Comment: So for each item created you will create a new list with its fields in this case, I think there is no problem to go ahead with this way:), please if the above answer guides you in the correct way please don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer to close the question Thanks!